# Function uses no argument error while collecting the test

Tags: python, selenium, nose

I have a problem with my pytest. Every time I run the test I get the following message:

In test_signup_customer_homepage: function uses no argument 'browser_name'

Here is my test file:

```
from nose.tools import istest

from fbtests.pages import Pages
from utils.misc import selenium_testcase

@istest
@selenium_testcase
 
 def test_signup_customer_homepage(driver):
 

    pages = Pages(driver)

    pages.home.visit('platform', 'homepage', '')
    pages.home.button_signup.wait_element_to_be_clickable()
    pages.home.button_signup.click()
```

Here is @isttest

```
def istest(func):

  func.__test__ = True
  return func
```

Here is @seleniumtestcase

```
  selenium_testcase = make_selenium_testcase(get_selenium_driver)
```

Comment: and that is the problem why?

Comment: Well, if you feel it's OK - no problem.

Comment: check arguments for pages.home.visit() method.